# if $f(x)$ absolutely integrable at $I=[0,\infty]$ and $f'(x)$ continuous and bounded at $I$ then $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(f\left(x\right)\right)=0$

Tags: calculus, integration

1.We know that $\lim _{t\to \infty }\left(\int _0^t\:|f\left(x|\right)\right)=L\in \mathbb{R}$

2.We know that $\;\exists \:M>0$ such that $\forall \:x\in \:\left[0,\infty \:\right] , \left|f'\left(x\right)\right|<M$

I tried to continue logically with this structure. But it's got me nowhere.Can I get help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)\neq 0$, that is, there is a $\varepsilon>0$ such that for any $n$, we can find a sequence $x_n>n$ such that $|f(x_n)|>\varepsilon.$

Now, we note that $f'$ is bounded continuous implies that $f$ is uniformly continuous. Hence, there is $\delta>0$ such that for all $|x-y|<\delta$ we have $|f(x)-f(y)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$

Thus, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, for all $t\in (x_n-\frac{\delta}{2},x_n+\frac{\delta}{2})$, we have 
$$
|f(t)-f(x_n)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}  \Rightarrow |f(x_n)|-|f(t)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2} \Rightarrow |f(t)|>|f(x_n)|-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}>\frac{\varepsilon}{2}. 
$$
WLOG, we assmue that $\{(x_n-\frac{\delta}{2},x_n+\frac{\delta}{2})\}$ is disjoint sequence of intervals.

Now, we observe that
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}|f(x)|dx \geq \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \int_{x_n-\delta/2}^{x_n+\delta/2} |f(x)|dx \geq \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \delta =\infty.
$$
It contradicts to the assumption that $f$ is absolutely integrable.